# How can I edit a .conf file easily?

Tags: bash, security, config, configuration-files

So I read the easiest way to use .conf files for `bash` scripts is to use `source` to load such files. Now, what if I want to edit this file ?

Some code I found does a really good job :

```
function set_config(){
    sed -i "s/^\($1\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$2/" $conf_file
}
```

But, if the variable is not yet defined, it doesn't define it, nor does it check if the parameters are passed well, isn't secure, doesn't handle default values etc...

Does reliable tools/code already exists to edit .conf file which contain key="value" pairs ? For instance, I would like to be able to do  things like this :

```
$conf_file="my_script.conf"
conf_load $conf_file #should create the file if it doesn't exist !
read=$(conf_get_value "data" "default_value") #should read the value with key "data", defaulting to "default_value"
if [[ $? = 0 ]] #we should be able to know if the read was successful
then
    echo "Successfully read value for field \"data\" : $read"
else
    echo "Default value for field \"data\" : $read"
fi

conf_set "something_new" "a great value!" #should add the key "something_new" as it doesn't exist
conf_set "data" "new_value" #should edit the value with key "data"
if [[ $? = 0 ]]
then
    echo "Edit successful !"
else #something went wrong :-/
    echo "Edit failed !"
fi
```

before running this code, the conf file would contain

```
data="some_value"
```

and after it would be

```
data="new_value"
something_new="a great value!"
```

and the code should output

```
Successfully read value for field "data" : some_value
Edit successful !
```

I am using `bash` version 4.3.30 .
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give us some example before and after data?

Comment: @Mr.Llama Edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd to that with `awk` since it's rather good at tokenizing:

```sh
# overwrite config's entries for KEY with VALUE or else appends the definition
# Usage: set_config KEY VALUE
set_config() {
  [ -n "$1" ] && awk -F= -v key="$1" -v new="$1=\"$2\"" '
    $1 == key { $0 = new; key_found = 1; }
    { print }
    END { if (!key_found) { print new; }
  ' "$conf_file" > "$conf_file.new" \
  && cat "$conf_file.new" > "$conf_file" && rm "$conf_file.new"
}
```

If run without arguments, `set_config()` will do nothing and return false.  If run with only one argument, it will create an empty value (outputting `KEY=""`).

The `awk` command parses the .conf file line by line, looking for each definition of the given key and altering it to the new value.  All lines are then printed (with or without modification), preserving the original order.  If the key hasn't yet been found by the end of the file, this appends the new definition.

Because you can't pipe a file atop itself, this gets saved with a ".new" extension and then copied atop the original in a manner that preserves permissions.  The ".new" copy is then removed.  I used `&&` to ensure that these never happen if an error occurred earlier in the function.

Also note that the type of ".conf file" you're referring to (the type you source with a POSIX shell) will never have spaces around its equals signs, so the `\s*` parts of your `sed` command aren't needed.

Comment: This looks like a very good start, is it secure for values containing special characters etc ... ?
What happens if only one argument is passed ?

Comment: I didn't put in a condition for too few arguments.  Zero arguments will add a bare equals sign at the end of the file and will create errors when the file is sourced.  One argument (or a blank second argument) will merely define the key as an empty string.  Special characters will work fine, though you'll have to quote them when passing to the `set_config()` function.

Comment: Is it case-sensitive ? Can this behaviour be changed ?
If such a functionnality doesn't exist yet in bash, would it be a good idea to make a package out of it ?

Comment: This code is indeed case sensitive.  Shell variables are case sensitive, so you want to stick with that, but if you really wanted to change that, you could do `tolower($1) == tolower(key)` in place of the above `$1 == key`

Comment: Having a package which regroups secured creation / reading / editing of conf files would really come in handy, imho... if anyone is up for the task :)

Comment: I have edited the code to reject empty arguments and accept a single argument as an assignment of the given key to an empty value (as now noted in the description).  I also added quotes in the conf file, as you'd otherwise run into issues with spaced values.